# Padding a multidimensional array with array_pad?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

```
$summary=$query->result_array();    //where the original array is created 
print_r($summary);                     //dump contents
```

Produces this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [RecordID] => 2 [UserID] => 3 [BookID] => 1 [Title] => FirstBook ) [1] => Array ( [RecordID] => 3 [UserID] => 3 [BookID] => 2 [Title] => Sequel ) )
```

I would now like to pad the multi dimensional array with a price element so as to create the results of

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [RecordID] => 2 [UserID] => 3 [BookID] => 1 [Title] => FirstBook [Price] => 99 ) [1] => Array ( [RecordID] => 3 [UserID] => 3 [BookID] => 2 [Title] => Sequel  [Price] => 99) )
```

The only way I can think of doing this is to break the multidimensional array into one-dimensional arrays, modify them, and then re-assemble them. Doesn't sound terribly efficient though. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the internal arrays by reference, note the `&` here:

```
foreach($summary as &$details){
    $details['Price'] = $price;  // wherever $price comes from...
}
```

Comment: Quick question: What is the technical name of that ampersand that you highlighted? "note the & here". It's not an operator is it? I'm trying to read up about it in PHP documentation.

Comment: @Maxcot read [assigment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) and [references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php)

Answer (score 0):

try to use:

```
foreach ($summary as $idx => &$arrValue)
    $arrValue['Price'] = ###;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're fixed on your dimensions, iterate with a reference and modify $summary in place...

```
<?php
foreach ($summary as &item) {
   $item['price'] = 99;
}
```

If you have particular objections/issues with references:

```
<?php
foreach ($summary as $key=>item) {
   $summary[$key]['price'] = 99;
}
```